# Getting "Error initializing cluster data" in OpsCenter

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I am getting following error in Opscenter, after some time the issue got resolved itself.

```
Error initializing cluster data: The request to 
/APP_Live/keyspaces?ksfields=column_families%2Creplica_placement_strategy%2Cstrategy_options%2Cis_system%2Cdurable_writes%2Cskip_repair%2Cuser_types%2Cuser_functions%2Cuser_aggregates&cffields=solr_core%2Ccreate_query%2Cis_in_memory%2Ctiers timed out after 10 seconds.. 

If you continue to see this error message, you can workaround this timeout by setting [ui].default_api_timeout to a value larger than 10 in opscenterd.conf and restarting opscenterd. 
Note that this is a workaround and you should also contact DataStax 
Support to follow up.
```

Comment: If the issue was intermittent this sounds like it may be a loading issue with the cluster.  Do you have any metrics from the before, during and after time that the cluster was experiencing the issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround of this timeout is by setting [ui].default_api_timeout to a value larger than 10 in opscenterd.conf and restarting opscenterd.